# Is this set theory used by Gandy first-order with signature $(\in, \lambda)$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

In *On the Axiom of Extensionality, Part II*, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 24, No. 4 (Dec., 1959),  https://doi.org/10.2307/2963897, pp. 287-300, R. O. Gandy shows that a class theory X containing NBG *minus extensionality* is not weaker than NBG; X includes a use of class-abstraction denoted with $\lambda$, so that $\lambda x(x=x)$ is a universal class.  Gandy does have identity. It is worth noticing that one can show (use A2 p. 289 and I29 p. 290) that  $x\in \lambda z\phi(z)\leftrightarrow \exists y(x\in y)\wedge\phi(x)$. Is X a first-order theory with signature $(\in, \lambda)$?

Comment: First-order logic is usually not defined in a way that would allow for an operator that turns formulas into terms. This formalism can be encoded in first-order logic, but would require a larger language with a function symbol for each $\lambda$ expression.

Comment: @JamesHanson is completely correct, but adding $\lambda$ is a definitional extension: _recursively_ replace $x \in \lambda z\phi(z)$ by $\phi(x)$ to obtain an equivalent first-order formula for the $\in$-language. I forget exactly how Gandy approaches it, but this does _not_ work for the language with equality but it does work if $x = y$ is interpreted in the $\in$-language as $\forall z(z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y)$. (IIRC, this is one of Gandy's key observations.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Gandy does have identity. It is worth noticing that one can show (use A2 p. 289 and I29 p. 290) that $x \in \lambda z\phi(z)\leftrightarrow \exists y(x \in y \land \phi(x))$. I will edit this into the question.

Comment: You're right, the correct translation for $x \in \lambda z\,\phi(z)$ is $\exists y(x \in y \land \phi(z))$ since we need to ensure that $x$ is a set and not a proper class.

Comment: The problem with equality is correctly translating $x = \lambda z\,\phi(z)$ which is where extensionality comes into play...

Comment: From Gandy's extract on  https://doi.org/10.2307/2963897: "In this paper it is shown that, if a certain form of Gödel-Bernays set theory which does not include the axiom of extensionality is consistent, then so is the whole system of set theory. The general line of argument is similar to that used in Part I. § 1 describes a reformulation of set theory in which the class-existence axioms are replaced by the use of abstracts."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A signature of first order [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) is usually taken to be a list of extra-logical symbols that range over specific elements (for constants) or over specific subsets (for n+1 ary functions, predicates) of the universe of discourse. The class-abstraction symbol $\lambda$ here doesn't fit into any of those. I'm not sure if it can be considered among symbols of the underlying logic, but by then that kind of logic won't be called just first order, one may call it first order logic with class-abstractions, or something to that effect. That said, I think the signature of Gandy's theory if described in terms of first order logic then it would be very extensive (in agreement with comment by James Hanson), so if $ \{x_i: i \in \mathbb N \}$ is the set of all variable symbols in a langauge, and  $\{\phi_j(x_i): i,j \in \mathbb N \}$ is the set of all formulas in one free variable in the language then the signature would be something like: $(=,\in, \lambda x_i \phi_j(x_i): i,j \in \mathbb N)$, a countably infinite signature! Where each $\lambda x_i \phi_j(x_i)$ is a constant (zero place function) symbol, i.e. an argumentless (doesn't take an *element* of the universe of discourse as argument) expression that range over a single element of the universe of discourse. However, if $n$ many free variables other than $x_i$ are allowed to occur in $\phi_j(x_i)$, then the expression $\lambda x_i \phi_j(x_i)$ would become an $n$-ary function symbol. In nutshell X *is* a first order theory with signature $(=,\in, \lambda x_i \phi_j(x_i): i,j \in \mathbb N)$

Comment: Gandy's theory X seems to be precisely NBG-set theory without extensionality plus set abstracts. NBG is first order. 

Notice, as I point out in the last paragraph of the question, that the $\lambda-terms$ do not in general support the naive abstraction schema. Let for instance $R$ be $\lambda y(y\notin y)$. We will have $\forall x(x\in R\leftrightarrow(\exists y(x\in y)\wedge x\notin x)$, so $R\notin R$ and $\lnot \exists y(R\in y)$. So the extensions of the lambda-terms do not correspond exactly to the defining conditions. 

Why should we think that X is not first order?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, I don't understand the question in your comment. OF course X is first order but its first order with the extensive signature I've written, it is an extension of first order language with $\lambda x_i \phi_j(x_i)$ constants.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, is the first order language Gandy use for NBG-Extensionality theory mono-sorted or bi-sorted?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, I asked about the sorting of the language because if its bisorted then $\lambda z \phi(z)$ would be a constant term denoting a CLASS (i.e. second sort object) while $z$ written in lower case is a first sort object (a set), so the term $\lambda z (z \not \in z)$ does support a naive abstraction schema, if it denotes $R$, then $R$ is exactly the class of all sets that are not in themselves, and $R \not \in R$ is irrelevant! If the language is mono-sorted, then $\lambda z (\exists y(z \in y) \land z \not \in z)$ is the correct expression.

Comment: Why is $\lambda x_i\,\phi_j(x_i)$ a constant? Does that mean that $\phi_j$ has no free variables other than $x_i$? Why can't we have free variables here?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, I thought $\phi_j$ has only one free variable $x_i$. If it has $n$-parameters (free variables other than $x_i$) then obviousely $\lambda x_i \phi_j (x_i)$ would be an $n$-ary function. I'll edit my response to that effect.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar On [I don't understand the ...]: My first comment was partly based upon a misreading of you, because your sentence "In nutshell X is a first order theory with signature $(=, \in, x_i\phi_j(x_i):i,j\in\mathbb{N}))$" was not edited in. I stand by what I state before the question in light of a comment below.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar On [I asked about the sorting of ...]: It is bi-sorted. But notice the comprehension principle I deduce at the end of my question. Gandy has I28:  $\mathbf{B}=_{D}\lambda x.x=x$ on p 289. I interpret $\lambda x.x=x$ as the (proper) class of all sets, and $Y\in\lambda x.x=x\leftrightarrow\exists Z(Y\in Z)\wedge Y=Y$. So my use of $\lambda y(y\notin y)$ seems to conform with Gandy's language use.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar "The primitive symbols of the system are $\mathbf{Cls}$, $\mathbf{M}$, $\in$, $=$, $\lambda$ and the symbols of the predicate calculus. There are two types of variable - capital and lower case letters - having  $\mathbf{Cls}$ and $\mathbf{M}$ as their respective ranges. A bold face lower-case letter denotes an arbitrary lower-case variable, while a bold face capital denotes an arbitrary variable of either type."

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I agree that $\phi_j$ should be allowed to have other free variables. Moreover, however, we should allow that $\phi_j$ is a sentence.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I agree that $\phi_j$ should be allowed to have other free variables. Moreover, however, we should allow that $\phi_j$ is a sentence.

Comment: My comments above need Gandy's first four axioms:

A. 1: $\mathbf{Cls}(x)$

A2: $X\in Y\supset \mathbf{M}(X)$

B'1: $\mathbf{Cls} (\lambda x.\phi)$

B'2: $(x \in\lambda x.\phi)\equiv \phi$, *provided* $x$ does not occur bound in $\phi$. Note that if it is required to deduce $\alpha\in\lambda x.\phi(x)$ from $\phi(\alpha)$, it is also necessary to prove $\mathbf{M}(\alpha)$. p. 289. These alone entail the comprehension principle I adduce at the end of my question.

Comment: In sum, may the signature be $(=,\in,\lambda x_i\phi_j)$, $i, j\in \mathbb{N}$, where $\{\phi_j|j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is the set of all formulas (primitive propositional functions, p. 288)?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, but if the theory is bi-sorted and lower cases range over "members" of classes, then we can easily deduce from your rules the theorem: $\forall x (x \in \lambda z. \phi(z) \iff \phi(x))$, this is actually axiomatized. While your $x\in \lambda z\phi(z)\leftrightarrow \exists y(x\in y)\wedge\phi(x)$ would be taken to mean that $x$ is an element of an element (notice that $y$ is lower case)? Is that what you want to say that all elements of $\lambda z. \phi(z)$ are elements of elements and that they must fulfil $\phi$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Gandy's use of a bisorted language is inessential, and is not needed. $\mathbf{Cls}$, $\mathbf{M}$ and capital letters can be eliminated, and we may take the quantifiers to range over all classes. The comprehension principle I suggest we presuppose is the one at the end of my question. You cannot deduce $\forall x(x\in \lambda z.\phi(z)\leftrightarrow\phi(x))$ from anything I have suggested, as you propose.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, if you make the quantifie range over all classes wouldn't that make it MK. Anyhow I think (not sure really) that MK and even NBG is equivalent to their versions without extensionality, even a class abstraction principle is not needed. It can be done in the ordinary language of class\set theory.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Indeed, Gandy's theory, X,  is almost MK. But it does not have extensionality. Gandy's point was to account for NBG with extensionality in a theory X which contains NBG without extensionality. 

Indeed, Dana Scott's More on the Axiom of Extensionality, in Essays on the Foundation of Mathematics: Dedicated to Abraham Fraenkel, Amsterdam, 1962, pp. 115-131, showed that a version of ZFC minus extensionality interprets ZFC without making use of set abstracts. I was interested in Gandy's account for other reasons, and do not now take set abstracts as an expressive disadvantage.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar On [Anyhow I think (not sure really) that MK and even NBG is equivalent to their versions without extensionality...] It was the point of Gandy's article to establish one of the directions concerning NBG and NBG without extensionality. Do we know that NBG accounts for Gandy's theory X, which unlike NBG has class abstracts?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Just as a reminder, my question was not concerned with the equivalences, but rather with the signature appropriate for Gandy's X.